# BPMN multiple diagrams in one model

Tags: model, modeling, diagram, bpmn

There are many ways and tools for creating a BPMN diagram, but what can one use to create a model  (with multiple diagrams)? I dont see the option in Camunda for example, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When you upgrade the modeler to 5.0 you will see that embedded sub processes can now be collapse again. This creates a second diagram in the BPMN and links to it. Will this suit your requirement?

There is also a community-developed plugin:
https://github.com/sharedchains/camunda-modeler-plugin-multidiagram
I have not tested it modeler v5 though.

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for, but rather havng a *model* with multiple (separate) diagrams and their elements and relations and so on.

Comment: You mean different views on the same model. Also, not quite what you mean I guess, but you may still like: https://github.com/sharedchains/camunda-layering-plugin

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you are looking for is provided by applications that support enterprise architecture management. I have been using Erwin Casewise and there you start by creating a model, to which you then associate diagrammes.